# Dojo Dgrid: select deselect of header checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, dojo, dgrid

I am using Dojo **"dgrid/OnDemandGrid"**.In that i am using its inbuilt functionality of check-box for each row.

The problem is whenever i am selecting all the check-boxes one by one then its header check-box i.e. select all check-box is not getting checked [image: Select All State] and same with whenever am deselecting all the check-boxes one by one then the select all check-box didn't get deselected remains in mixed state [image: Deselect All State]. There three states True,False and Mixed.

When i was searching a solution for this i found that its a bug in Dojo Dgrid itself.
This  is the URL where you can check.[DOjo Dgrid Sellect All functionality](http://dgrid.io/js/dgrid/test/Selector.html)

Please help me to resolve this issue, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The property used to updated the header checkbox (allSelected) is not updated when you select the rows individually. You might be right it might be a bug. Have you reported it?

The workaround solution I could think of is to update the state of the header checkbox yourself. Below is the code to do the same.

```
            grid.on('dgrid-select', function () {
                var selectedRows = [];
                for (var e in grid.selection) {
                    grid.selection[e] && selectedRows.push(e)
                }

                //get the selector column and checkbox from that column
                var column = grid.columns["select"];
                var headerCheckbox = column._selectorHeaderCheckbox;
                if (selectedRows.length === grid.get('total')) {
                    //update the checkbox when the selection count equal to total count.
                    headerCheckbox.indeterminate = false;
                    headerCheckbox.checked = true;
                    headerCheckbox.setAttribute('aria-checked', 'true');
                    grid.allSelected = true;
                }
            });

            grid.on('dgrid-deselect', function () {
                var selectedRows = [];
                for (var e in grid.selection) {
                    grid.selection[e] && selectedRows.push(e)
                }

                //get the selector column and checkbox from that column
                var column = grid.columns["select"];
                var headerCheckbox = column._selectorHeaderCheckbox;
                if (selectedRows.length === 0) {
                    headerCheckbox.indeterminate = false;
                    headerCheckbox.checked = false;
                    headerCheckbox.setAttribute('aria-checked', 'false');
                    grid.allSelected = false;
                }
            });
```

Hope this was helpful.